# How to preserve default SVG color with mat-icon?

Tags: css, angular, svg, angular-material

I have SVG of google symbol which is in 4 different colors. I want to use this SVG within my code with this colors using mat-icon. However when I tried to attach this SVG in my code it is turning black and white.

Here is my code for SVG attachment

```
   <mat-icon 
        svgIcon="google-icon">
   </mat-icon>
```

and SVG module declaration

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

const googleIcon = require( 'lib/images/font-icons/google-icon.svg' );

@NgModule()
export class GoogleIconSvgModule {
    constructor(
        private iconRegistry : MatIconRegistry,
        private sanitizer : DomSanitizer,
    ) {
        iconRegistry.addSvgIcon( 'google-icon',
            sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl( googleIcon ) );
    }
}
```

Sample SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#8EC3E5;}
    .st1{fill:#F4B61A;}
    .st2{fill:#787878;}
    .st3{fill:#A7C972;}
    .st4{fill:#E57E8F;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M181.6,0C81.3,0,0,32.5,0,72.6c0,7.7,0,35.9,0,43.6c0,40.1,81.4,72.6,181.6,72.6c100.4,0,181.6-32.5,181.6-72.6
    c0-7.7,0-35.9,0-43.6C363.2,32.5,282,0,181.6,0z"/>
<g>
    <path class="st1" d="M166.6,330.1c-63.4-2-127.5-16.5-166.2-44.8c0,0.5-0.3,1-0.3,1.5c0,7.7,0,35.9,0,43.6
        c0,38.1,73.4,69.3,166.6,72.4V330.1z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <path class="st2" d="M357.5,354.8c-7.6,0-13.7,2.7-18.3,8.1c-4.6,5.4-6.8,13.6-6.8,24.4c0,12.7,3.3,21.7,9.8,27.2
        c4.2,3.6,9.3,5.3,15.2,5.3c2.2,0,4.3-0.3,6.4-0.8c1.1-0.3,2.6-0.8,4.3-1.6l-9.3-8.9l9.9-10.4l9.4,8.8c1.5-3,2.5-5.6,3.1-7.9
        c0.9-3.4,1.4-7.3,1.4-11.8c0-10.4-2.1-18.4-6.4-24C371.9,357.6,365.7,354.8,357.5,354.8z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M491.9,308.5H216.6c-11,0-20,9-20,20V446c0,11,9,20,20,20h275.3c11,0,20-9,20-20V328.5
        C511.9,317.4,502.9,308.5,491.9,308.5z M293.3,427.7c-6.5,5.6-15.7,8.4-27.6,8.4c-12.2,0-21.7-2.7-28.7-8.2
        c-7-5.5-10.4-13-10.4-22.7H245c0.6,4.2,1.8,7.4,3.5,9.5c3.2,3.8,8.7,5.7,16.4,5.7c4.6,0,8.4-0.5,11.3-1.5c5.5-1.9,8.3-5.5,8.3-10.7
        c0-3-1.3-5.4-4-7.1c-2.7-1.6-7-3.1-12.8-4.3l-10-2.2c-9.8-2.2-16.6-4.5-20.3-7.1c-6.2-4.3-9.3-10.9-9.3-20c0-8.3,3-15.1,9.1-20.6
        c6.1-5.5,15-8.2,26.8-8.2c9.9,0,18.3,2.6,25.2,7.7c7,5.2,10.6,12.6,10.9,22.5h-18.5c-0.3-5.6-2.8-9.5-7.5-11.8
        c-3.1-1.5-6.9-2.3-11.5-2.3c-5.1,0-9.2,1-12.2,3c-3,2-4.6,4.8-4.6,8.4c0,3.3,1.5,5.8,4.5,7.4c1.9,1.1,6,2.4,12.3,3.8l16.2,3.8
        c7.1,1.7,12.4,3.9,16,6.7c5.5,4.3,8.3,10.6,8.3,18.9C303.1,415.1,299.9,422.1,293.3,427.7z M392.1,440.3L381,429.8
        c-3.4,2.1-6.3,3.5-8.8,4.3c-4.1,1.4-9.1,2.1-14.9,2.1c-12,0-22-3.6-29.9-10.8c-9.5-8.6-14.3-21.3-14.3-38.1
        c0-16.9,4.9-29.6,14.7-38.3c8-7.1,17.9-10.6,29.8-10.6c11.9,0,22,3.7,30.1,11.2c9.4,8.6,14,20.7,14,36.3c0,8.2-1,15.1-3,20.7
        c-1.6,5.3-4,9.7-7.2,13.2l10.6,10L392.1,440.3z M481.9,433.6h-65.4v-92.4h19.3V417h46.1V433.6z"/>
</g>
<path class="st3" d="M216.6,278.5h77.7c42-13.3,68.9-33.9,68.9-57c0-7.3,0-32.5,0-41.7c-41.7,30.7-113.3,45.3-181.6,45.3
    c-68.4,0-139.9-14.6-181.6-45.3c0,9.2,0,34.4,0,41.7c0,39.9,80.6,72.3,180.3,72.6C189.4,284.5,202.3,278.5,216.6,278.5z"/>
<g>
    <path class="st4" d="M216.6,496c-27.6,0-50-22.4-50-50v-7c-63.4-2-127.5-16.5-166.2-44.8c0,0.5-0.3,1-0.3,1.5c0,7.7,0,35.9,0,43.6
        C0,479.5,81.4,512,181.6,512c43,0,82.5-6,113.6-16H216.6z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Here I would like to get SVG as it is in 4 different colors instead of black and white.

Comment: I think this might be more of an issue of the SVG file itself. Could you share the SVG file XML code?

Comment: In my case the svg file had color embedded into it using the fill attribute.
I removed that and it started accepting colors from angular/css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mat icon by default, sets the color of the svgs you register, following the formula [mentioned in the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview)

> the default color of the SVG content is the CSS currentColor value.
>   This makes SVG icons by default have the same color as surrounding
>   text, and allows you to change the color by setting the "color" style
>   on the mat-icon element.

This is the default functionality and there is no way to change this. The color attribute onle gets three values from the theme css

- Primary
- Warn
- Accent

So, you need to either override it globally (thus destroying the theming of all the material icons) or per case.

The only options you have while registering is the viewport, so you'd have to go via the css way. The css that sets up the currentColor is the following:

```
.mat-icon {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    fill: currentColor;
}
```

In order to avoid that, I would declare in my global css files an override class, to declare per case

```
.mat-icon {
    .no-theme {
       fill: inherit;
    }
}
```

and apply the no-theme class to the target mat-icon declaration.